# Setting and storing a global boolean variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just recently, I have been doing my studies about the `global` variables in Python and fortunately, through stackoverflow.com, I was able to learn how to initialize `list`,`dict`,`int`,and `string` global variables.

My question is, is there any way for me to set the global variable into "empty" boolean?

The reason for this is:

I have a program which works like:

```
if global boolean is True:
    #do this
else:
    #do that
```

And I want the value of the boolean to be stored so that when I close and re-open the program, the value will be still there.

Comment: You could write the value in a file, update it and read it when necessary.

Comment: This is unrelated, but when you want to check whether a boolean value is true, you can just use `if myvar:`, instead of `if myvar == True` or `is True`. As far as your question is concerned, you would need to decide on some form of storage in which to put your data before the script ends. Do you want to store the values in a file? A database?

Comment: @user3404844 You can open a file using `with open('pathtofile.ext', 'w') as output_file:`. Then you can write to it inside the block using `output_file.write('Something I want to output')`. Reading it back can be done by opening the file again in read mode, i.e. `open('pathtofile.ext', 'r')`, and reading the data using the `.read()` method.

Comment: Insert "globals are a bad idea, try not to use them" rant here.